# Botium partial convos are not actually sending conversations to chatbot

Tags: automated-tests, chatbot

I am trying to follow the partial convo instructions [here](https://medium.com/@floriantreml/botium-in-a-nutshell-part-2-writing-chatbot-tests-8726204c8da6) under splitting convos, but I am unable to get the partial convo to actually send messages to the chatbot. Are there additional configuration settings in `botium.json` that I need to adjust to enable this feature?

Consider the simple `give_me_a_picture.convo.txt` that is created with botium-cli init. If I create a `pconvo.txt` file `example.pconvo.txt` that looks like this:

```
PARTIAL_HELLO

#me
Hello, Bot!

#bot
You said: Hello, Bot!
```

and then I adjust `give_me_a_picture.convo.txt` to include the following:

```
give me picture

INCLUDE PARTIAL_HELLO

#me
give me a picture

#bot
Here is a picture
MEDIA http://www.botium.at/img/logo.png
```

The above test will technically still pass. However, if I run this with `--verbose` you will see that it doesn't actually send the commands from `PARTIAL_HELLO` (ie. `"Hello, Bot!"`) -- it just skips to saying `give me a picture` -- what adjustments do I have to make such that it actually goes through the partial conversation?

Here is the `--verbose` output at the start of the convo where you can see the first question is `give me a picture`

```
botium-PluginConnectorContainer Botium plugin botium-connector-echo loaded +0ms
  botium-connector-echo Validate called +0ms
  botium-connector-echo Build called +1ms
  botium-connector-echo Start called +0ms
  botium-cli-run running testcase give me picture +21ms
  botium-Convo give me picture/Line 5: user says {
  botium-Convo   "sender": "me",
  botium-Convo   "channel": null,
  botium-Convo   "messageText": "give me a picture",
  botium-Convo   "stepTag": "Line 5",
  botium-Convo   "not": false,
  botium-Convo   "asserters": [],
  botium-Convo   "logicHooks": [],
  botium-Convo   "userInputs": []
  botium-Convo } +0ms
```

I can also confirm that botium did find the partial convo and transcribed it succesfully:

```
botium-ScriptingProvider  undefined PARTIAL_HELLO ({ convoDir: 'sample/', filename: 'example.pconvo.txt' }): Line 3: #me - Hello, Bot! | Line 6: #bot - You said: Hello, Bot! +0ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the INCLUDE instruction in the header of the convo file, which is the wrong place - you have to use it within the actual conversation. To use the partial convo at the beginning of the convo, add it in the *#begin* section:

```
give me picture

#begin
INCLUDE PARTIAL_HELLO

#me
give me a picture

#bot
Here is a picture
MEDIA http://www.botium.at/img/logo.png
```

Comment: Thank you! What about if I use it within the middle? Do I need a section header?

Comment: you can just add it to the section where it should be inserted