# Cannot include partial conversation in Botium Watson Assistant test with #include

Tags: automated-tests, chatbot

I tried following [partial conversation documentation](https://botium-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/05_botiumscript/index.html) to include a partial conversation file using `#include` syntax.

I want to use many partial conversations, not just in beginning/end but in middle of conversation as well.  Which is the correct syntax?

Error:

```
  context: {
    err: Error: Failed to parse conversation. Section "include" unknown.
        at linesToConvoStep (/Users/afreed/Code/workspace/my-botium-project/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/helper.js:76:38)
        at parseMsg (/Users/afreed/Code/workspace/my-botium-project/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/CompilerTxt.js:69:14)
        at pushPrev (/Users/afreed/Code/workspace/my-botium-project/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/CompilerTxt.js:79:34)
        at /Users/afreed/Code/workspace/my-botium-project/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/CompilerTxt.js:93:9
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at CompilerTxt._compileConvo (/Users/afreed/Code/workspace/my-botium-project/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/CompilerTxt.js:89:11)
        at CompilerTxt.Compile (/Users/afreed/Code/workspace/my-botium-project/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/CompilerTxt.js:43:19)
        at ScriptingProvider.Compile (/Users/afreed/Code/workspace/my-botium-project/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/ScriptingProvider.js:407:21)
        at ScriptingProvider.ReadScript (/Users/afreed/Code/workspace/my-botium-project/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/ScriptingProvider.js:493:27)
        at /Users/afreed/Code/workspace/my-botium-project/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/ScriptingProvider.js:452:71,
    message: `ReadScript - an error occurred at 'immediate-pound-out_with_partial.convo.txt' file: Failed to parse conversation. Section "include" unknown.`
  }
```

Test convo `immediate-pound-out_with_partial.convo.txt`:

```
immediate pound out, templated second strike

#bot
Hi, how can I help you?

#me
0
UPDATE_CUSTOM SET_WATSON_CONTEXT|vgwIsDTMF|"Yes"

#bot
I can't handle DTMF here

#me
0
UPDATE_CUSTOM SET_WATSON_CONTEXT|vgwIsDTMF|"Yes"

#include SECOND-STRIKE

#bot
Please hold while I transfer you
```

If I replace `#include SECOND-STRIKE` with the following, it works.  (This seems odd - effectively defining `#bot` section twice.)

```
#bot
INCLUDE SECOND-STRIKE
```

Partial convo file `second-strike.pconvo.txt`:

```
SECOND-STRIKE

#bot
I still didn't understand.
```

Found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55774072/botium-partial-convos-are-not-actually-sending-conversations-to-chatbot), which is unclear about adding partials in the middle of a conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *#include* syntax is only available with the most recent release 1.11.2 Please check your Botium Core version